# unable to edit a power-point presentation. Error "We can not open this presentation because it is protected with IRM."

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, irm, powerpoint

We have a power-point presentation inside our online document library, but if the users try to edit the presentation using the browser they will get this error:-

[image]

and if i chose to open in the desktop app i will keep getting this message:-
[image]

Although when i access:- Admin centers >> SharePoint >> settings >> classic settings page >> In the Information Rights Management (IRM), i found that we are not using IRM, as follow:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the IRM permissions are stored within the PowerPoint document itself, therefore I don't think this is a SharePoint problem. You can find more information on this here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-a-file-that-has-restricted-permissions-c7a70797-6b1e-493f-acf7-92a39b85e30c